# Mixed Model Repeated Measures (MMRM)

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, residuals, generalized-least-squares

I should specify a repeated measures model where I have two visits for each patient (number of patients =100).

I am asking:

**1)    is this model below correctly specified as a repeated measures model? Could you please write down the mathematical formula that describes it?**

```
mmrm <- gls(Outcome~ Treatment+Visit+ Treatment*Visit, data=sim, corr=corSymm(form= ~ 1 |patient_id), weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | Visit))
```

Also, if I apply the formula *resid(mmrm)* I get a split output, the first 200 residuals (100 patients with two visits each) are all different, while the second 200 are all the same per visit. To test for normality I would say that I only need to consider the first 200 residuals of the output, so

```
my_resid<-head(resid(mmrm),100)
```

**2) Could you tell me exactly what these *my_resid* are and maybe write down the mathematical formula?**

Answer (score 1):

Generalized least squares can definitely model repeated measurements per subject, although this may better be labeled as longitudinal data to denote that time is important.  Speaking of time, your model does not use time so you are assuming that visits occur at specific days that are the same days for all subjects.  If that is not the case it is better to use a continuous time model with a continuous time correlation structure with `gls`.  If you continue to use `visit` instead of `time` and there are only two visits, the correlation structure you assume is irrelevant.

`gls` does not fit random effects, so strike "mixed" in the title of your post.

Don't create a `TreatmentVisit` variable but instead let R know that you are dealing with an interaction term.  Specify `Treatment * Visit` to create all the main effects and interaction terms automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Thus for it to be a MMRM (Mixed Model Repeated Measures), I'd say it's probably best to specify it as below, to get the random component.


mmrm<-lme(Outcome ~ Treatment+Visit+Treatment*Visit, random = ~ 1| Patient_Id, correlation = corCompSymm(form = ~ Visit | Patient_Id), weights=varIdent(form=~1|Visit),control=lmeControl(opt = "optim"), data = sim)

Or would you have a suggestion? The visits are exactly the same days for all subjects.

Comment: I should have clarified that.   I think you need at least 4 observations per subject to use random effects.  So I'd stick with generalized least squares with a correlation pattern that depends on whether or not visits are spaced the same in days for all subjects.